# My father is better than your father

Tags: midrash, adam, satan

Posting for someone else:

The Talmud ([Sanhedrin 37a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.37a.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) writes that one reason that Adam was created alone was "so that one person will not say to another: My father, i.e., progenitor, is greater than your father."

Yet, Pirkei Derabbi Eliezer ([Chapter 21](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.21.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)) writes that Kayin was not fathered by Adam, but rather fathered by Sama'el, who rode [?] the Nachash.

Assuming that the reason given by the Talmud is also relevant to a second generation (which is the simple read of that passage), is there any way to reconcile these two midrashim with each other?

Comment: Funner title "my father is better than Kayin's father?"

Comment: Yet Bereishis Rabbah 22:2 says that Kayin was fathered by Adam - אָמַר לֵיהּ רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בֶּן קָרְחָה עָלוּ לַמִּטָּה שְׁנַיִם וְיָרְדוּ שִׁבְעָה, קַיִּן וּתְאוֹמָתוֹ, וְהֶבֶל וּשְׁתֵּי תְאוֹמוֹתָיו

Comment: @Dov But can Adam be defined as Samael also? Either as Adam Belial, or as Esau who sometimes get conflated with Samael? The definitions are not always exact, sometimes some sources they say two closely figures are different levels of the same entity or energy, sometimes they conflate them directly as being the same, so how do we deal with that? There are two creation stories of Adam in Bereshit, and some say one is an Adam with a soul and one is an Adam like an animal.

Answer (score 1):

[Rabbeinu Bachya](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Bereshit.5.2.4?ven=Torah_Commentary_by_Rabbi_Bachya_ben_Asher,_trans._Eliyahu_Munk,_1998.&lang=bi) takes the middle ground which would perhaps provide a compromise.

> ועוד נראה לומר [זה ספר תולדות אדם](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.5.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) כי הכונה על שת שיזכיר בפרשה. ולפי שב' הבנים שהיו לו האחד נהרג והב' נתקלל ונתקיים זרעו בשת אמר עליו זה ספר תולדות אדם כי הוא לבדו תולדותיו החשובים. **ואע"פ שכבר הגיד הכתוב עד עתה תולדות רבות לקין לא היו תולדותיו של אדם כי אם תולדות חוה מרוכב הנחש, הוא סמאל**, והם חנוך ועירד ולמך. ומהם חתומים בשם אל כשמות המלאכים והם מחוייאל ומתושאל. ועל תולדות אלה של קין אמר הכתוב ויראו בני האלהים את בנות האדם. כי היו בני האלהים לא בני אדה"ר. **וע"ז דרשו רז"ל זה ספר תולדות אדם אלו תולדות אדם ואין הראשונים תולדות אדם** ומה הן אלוהות כי לכך קראן אלוהות לפי שכולן נולדו מקין שנולד מחוה מכח אל נכר, והבן זה.
>
> Another meaning of the words זה ספר תולדות אדם may be that these words are a direct reference to שת who is (directly) mentioned in the Parsha. Accordingly, the two sons of his (Kayin & Hevel) - one was killed and the second was cursed, thus his (Adam's) seed was preserved through Sheis and this is the book of generations of Adam, and so he alone are the important descendants. **And even though the Torah has so far related many descendants, the descendants of Kayin were not the descendants of Adam but rather the descendants of Chava from the rider of the snake, Samael.** These descendants were Chanoch, Iyrad, and Lemech. And from them are signed in the name of G-d as the names of the angels, and they are  Mechuyael and Mesushael. And with regards to the descendants of Kayin that verse says, "And the sons of G-d saw the daughters of man", for they were the sons of G-d and not the children of Adam. **And about this, our Rabbis of blessed memory expound that the Book of Descendants of Adam - these are indeed the descendants of Adam, but not the first descendants (my point: important to note though whilst not the first they are the true descendants of Adam)** What then is the meaning of the verse which appears to attribute some of the descendants of Kayin to a divine origin? It is because they were all born from Kayin who was from Chava from (lit.) the strength of a stranger (i.e. Samael).

So based on this perhaps we can make a compromise, while Kayin can be seen as the product of Chava and the Satan, he is still grouped among the descendants of Adam even though he wasn't truly from him which would at least satisfy the Gemara in Sanhedrin.

Comment: Similarly, perhaps we can suggest that since Chavah was created from Adam, Kayin was therefore a descendant of Adam as well.