# Was Man Created Alone?

Tags: creation, adam, gan-eden, eve-chava

I am looking for a source which I (thought I) came across once regarding creation of man. From what I remember it said that man was actually created in multiple places. Or rather more than one man was created and in different places. This contrasts the popular and simple reading as well that Adam was created as an individual and everyone came from Adam and Chava.

I thought it was Abarbanel, but I have not located it again. Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: That man was created from dust from the 4 corners of the earth?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. Yes that is true. I am aware of that medrash. But what I believe I saw was that man or rather men were created from the earth in addition to Adam in other places.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/125583/my-father-is-better-than-your-father

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of the position of the Tifereth Yisrael who discusses the existence of prehominids/hominids prior to Adam?

Comment: I thought I saw something that went a step further. But where is that TY?